# How to use vectors<int> to do extremely large integer multiplication

Tags: c++

I am trying to use vectors to do very large multiplication and I keep running into an issue when running my algorithm.

```
vector<vector<int>> finalresult;
vector<int> currentrow;
int carry=0, workingnum=0, innerval =0, curnt=0, j=0;

for (auto an = a.rbegin(); an != a.rend(); ++an)
{
    for (auto bn = b.rbegin(); bn != b.rend(); ++bn)
    {
        curnt = (*an) * (*bn);
        if (curnt > 10 && carry ==0)
        {
            carry = curnt / 10;
            currentrow.push_back(curnt % 10);
        }
        if (curnt < 10 && carry ==0)
        {
            currentrow.push_back(curnt);
        }
        if (curnt < 10 && carry >0)
        {
            if ((curnt + carry) < 10)
            {
                currentrow.push_back(curnt + carry);
            }
            else
            {
                workingnum = curnt + carry;
                carry = workingnum / 10;
                currentrow.push_back(workingnum % 10);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            workingnum = curnt + carry;
            carry = workingnum / 10;
            currentrow.push_back(workingnum % 10);
        }

    }
    finalresult.push_back(currentrow);
    for (int i = 0; i < currentrow.capacity(); i++)
    {
        currentrow.pop_back();
    }
    for (int i=0; i < j; i++)
    {
        currentrow.push_back(0);
    }
    j++;
}
```

Each time this code runs if it hits one of the inner if statements like if curnt < 10 and carry ==0, it will push_back curnt, but then it does it again in the else section as well. I can not under stand why its happening in the else section as well. (i know thats what is happening because of debugging) can any one shed some light on this?

Comment: how about look in wikipedia for bignum libraries? i think most use the gnu something.

Comment: I suggest you comment your code. It's probably easier to analyse your code if you leave breadcrumbs for yourself. This is not really a code problem, but a documentation/intent/clarity problem.

Comment: Also, what about the case where **curnt == 10?**

Comment: I have comments on my end of things, felt that they didnt need to be in here so i took them out. curnt == 10 is handled in the else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
if (curnt < 10 && carry >0)
{
    if ((curnt + carry) < 10)
    {
        currentrow.push_back(curnt + carry);
    }
    else
    {
        workingnum = curnt + carry;
        carry = workingnum / 10;
        currentrow.push_back(workingnum % 10);
    }
}
else
{
    workingnum = curnt + carry;
    carry = workingnum / 10;
    currentrow.push_back(workingnum % 10);
}
```

Either the `if` block or the `else` block will be executed no matter what you did prior to that `if` line.

**Simplify**

You can replace

```
if (curnt > 10 && carry ==0)
{
   carry = curnt / 10;
   currentrow.push_back(curnt % 10);
}
if (curnt < 10 && carry ==0)
{
   currentrow.push_back(curnt);
}
if (curnt < 10 && carry >0)
{
   if ((curnt + carry) < 10)
   {
      currentrow.push_back(curnt + carry);
   }
   else
   {
      workingnum = curnt + carry;
      carry = workingnum / 10;
      currentrow.push_back(workingnum % 10);
   }
}
else
{
   workingnum = curnt + carry;
   carry = workingnum / 10;
   currentrow.push_back(workingnum % 10);
}
```

by

```
curnt += carry;
carry = curnt / 10;
currentrow.push_back(curnt % 10);
```

Comment: is the else only tied to the if statement right above the else statement? if thats the case should all the if's minus the first one be 'else ifs'?

Comment: @Lupus, yes and yes. You can also use the simplified version I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @R Sahu, Ahh, i didnt not understand that you were suggesting replace everything there. Thanks for the answer.